# Are results returned by Google Place API different when searching in Google Maps on web?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

When I search "able pest management" on Google Maps web, i get a result but when I do it on Google API Place Autocomplete, it gives me no result. My client is concerned on the discrepancies.

Comment: Yes, the results can be different.

Comment: I think people are down voting because is not "coding" related question. Totally legit question otherwise